# What is the best way (using solid state) to power off lights when another light circuit powers on?

Tags: transistors, mosfet, led, switching

I am trying to build a circuit that will turn off LED license plate (LP) lights with the LED backup (BU) lights come on. The reasoning for this is that the LP lights wash out the reverse camera due to brightness and their close proximity to the camera.
In my rudimentary schematic, I just plopped in switches for the relay system that's actually used in the car. For simplicity I didn't put resisters on the LED's because they're built in to the lights.
Basically, SW1 is always on/closed. Whenever SW2 is closed I need the LP node to switch off.
LP lights are 0.5W each at 12.8V
BU lights are 2.3W each at 12.8V
I had been looking into using a MOSFET for controlling the LP node, but I don't know if that's the best thing to use (or which one). Any design help and/or component specs is appreciated.

I should explicitly mention this is for an automotive application.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fjQXhZ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: if you want a simple solution, then just use an automotive relay. Just visit your local self serve car wreckers and there's a zillion relays at your feet along with sockets, fuses etc. Also a fine selection of lamps and fasteners. You want yourself a change-over relay - one with normally open (the common type) and normally closed. Wire the normally closed contacts in series with the LP circuit and the coil in parallel with the relay coil of SW2. Job done. You could play around with mosfets etc, but if this is just a one-off, then relays will do your job just fine.

Comment: *component recommendations would be appreciated.* <-- Questions seeking recommendations for specific products or places to purchase them are off-topic

Comment: Thanks for the info Kartman. I'm really looking for a solution with mosfets, etc. I think it'd make for a fun project and a much smaller package. I'm going to try and place this under the trunk lid somewhere safe and near the wiring for the lights.

Comment: ‘Under the trunk lid’ means potential high temperatures, vibrations and electrical interference. By the time you’ve designed the circuit using a mosfet to survive the harsh under hood conditions, you could have selected a suitable, off the shelf automotive relay, wired, tested it and had a beer. You don’t need a degree in engineering to choose a suitable relay vs having to engineer a circuit using a mosfet. Engineering time costs money. What advantage would a mosfet give in your application? Especially if it’s a one-off?

Comment: I'm not too worried about temps getting high since it's not the engine compartment (I was meaning the rear luggage compartment by 'trunk' but at this point I might just go with some small solid state relays. Thanks for taking time to respond, i do appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

A solid-state switch is one way to power off lights when another light circuit is powered on.
To use a solid-state switch, first identify the outlets in both rooms where the lights are being used and then purchase one or more packs of single outlet Solid State Switches. Connect each SSS outlet with the desired lamp(s) using wire leads for convenience while installing or prewired cables. When it's time to power down the lamps, flip a button on each SSS pack, and all associated lamps will be turned off simultaneously.

Comment: Thanks Sakshi, but this is for an automotive application. I updated my question to indicate that. I didn't know there was such a thing as solid state switches for AC lighting in homes though. Thanks for that bit of info.